# How do I make page number in footer to be away 2cm from content?

Tags: microsoft-word, footers

I am writing a dissertation and my page numbers in the footer have to be 2 cm away from the content, how do I do that?

I am using MS Word 2007, Windows.

On some pages I think it is and on some pages I dont think it looks like it is. The lady that is revising my dissertation will deny my paper once again if I dont make this rule happen.
Please help.

[image]

Comment: It depends on how your document is set up. Are you using "different first page" formatting for each section of the document?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the following steps:

1. Make sure that **Ruler** is selected in the **View** tab
2. Drag the ruler bar up, as needed. Note that the metrics shown correspond to your [Word measure settings](http://www.howtogeek.com/169302/how-to-change-the-ruler-measurement-unit-in-word-2013/)
3. Position the cursor on the page number in the footer and press Enter until 2 cm distance is made

[image]

Comment: Thank you Milena so much! I hope this will work for the revision lady at school. I know this works but if they measure and its 2,5 or something like that from the last text, she denies. They are so uptight, even though the settings are correct. :/
Thanks again! :)

Comment: You're welcome, Tine, keeping my fingers crossed. Can you ask what solution they recommend and share it here? We can all learn something new. BTW, you can adjust the line size in the footer by changing the font, and thus additionally tweak the size

Comment: At school they have no clue nor they don't care. They just set the rules, measure them and if its not according their made up standards they deny the dissertation(diploma). That is it. I wish they were educated in that aspect and open but they are not.:/ Thanks! :)